# Starting to use PHP namespaces in an existing repository, all files give syntax errors

Tags: php, utf-8, namespaces

Having replaced the normal `<?php` with `<?php namespace foo;` on each file in my main source I received the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in src/admin_house_videos.php on line 1

On a majority of files. Looking around the internet people suggest that something called `UTF8-BOM` is to blame, but how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Why do you only ask and answer your own questions? Very weird...

Comment: I answer a lot of questions and many of my questions have been answered by other people. However when I solve problems for which I haven't discovered a complete end-to-end solution to online I like to post them to help others, which is why the site encourages Q&A style answers.

Comment: Not saying there's anything wrong with it - I just went back through your post history and 99% of your questions were answered and accepted by yourself. No big deal, they seem to add value, just odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, helpfully, that Sublime Text was able to fix this problem on a per-file basis:

> File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF8

However on a large repository this would be time consuming. I then found [this guide](http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-remove-bom-from-utf-8) which suggested that the unix tool `awk` could be used to replace the file:

```
awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' file.php
```

However trying to write this back to the file with `> file.php` appended to the end blanked the file, presumably some sort of read/write issue with output is sent to stdout.

So a bash script needed to be written to solve the issue; in my case it was run from a root where the files were in `./src/` but change the `$dir` parameter to alter this. The `echo` line is just to report on progress.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="./src/"

for file in `find $dir -name "*.php"` ; do
    echo $file
    awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' $file > $file.awk
    mv $file.awk $file
done
```